# git-lfs/debian does not have a Release file

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, debian, git-lfs

Hello I am running the following docker image
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

The dockerfile installs **git-lfs**

So when I run **apt-get udpate**, I get the following error.

```
W: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/debian/dists/stretch/main/source/Sources  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Clicking on the link to the package (i.e. https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/debian) takes me to a page saying "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Is this some kind of external problem?

Is there a way that I can ignore this part of the update?

Any other ideas?

I've been googling and trying to think of workarounds for this for a full day and a half now.

Comment: Sometimes the certificate error occurs when your system time is out of sync. Have you ensured that's not the case? If that's the case, you may install `ntp` using command: `apt-get install ntp`

Comment: it says "Unable to locate package ntp", and I can't do an atp-get update, so..

Comment: i hacked the original dockerfile to install ntp before installing git-lfs and it fixed it! I don't really like hacking official dockerfiles, but I guess I don't have much of a choice. Thanks Technext

Comment: Glad it worked. Posting it as an answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sometimes the certificate error occurs when your system time is *out of sync*. If that's the case, you may install `ntp` using command: `apt-get install ntp`